# I have an issue running tests using remote webdriver (grid2) that works on local webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

I have a little issue with some Webdriver tests in order to make them run using grid2.

My first issue is, that some tests need to check something on another domain, for example, I start on domain AA and then check a result on domain BB. Going to domain BB when I run local is not a problem, but using grid (Launching from a hub and testing on clients) the tests stop in that step.

The other problem, is that many findby functions only works locally, but using remote webdriver they return a null pointer exception (By xpath for example). Why is webdriver finding elements when test are local and not when tests run on remote pcs?

As a clarification, in both PCs (Hub and node) test run perfectly when I run them local, but also, in both, they fail using remote webdriver.

Any clues about his?

Answer (score 0):

There could be number of reasons varying from browser, it's version, settings, OS etc. What browser are you talking about? What is your selenium version? Is this problem persistent on all browsers? Do your domains use secure protocol, HTTPS?  A few lines of code where you define remote webdriver would help too. Otherwise giving answer would be shooting in the dark.  Did you try Desired Capabilities? Something like below?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities =  DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);      
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT, true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("....."), capabilities);
```

Perhaps this will lead you to solution. If you are using IE then make sure the domains you are testing present in the trusted sites settings.